# Cakephp 2 - Redis - Docker | Connection Refused

Tags: php, docker, cakephp, redis, connection

I have troubleshot this to the end of the internet without any luck.

I am getting a "connection refused" error from cakes Cache.php

My engine is set to Redis, I have docker building the image properly (at-least I believe I do), everything appears to be correct but for the life of me I cannot get the cache engine to work.

Here is what I currently have set up:

**Dockerfile**
`RUN yes | apt-get install redis-server`

`RUN pecl install redis \`
`&&  echo "extension=redis.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/redis.ini \`
`&&  rm -rf /tmp/pear`

**docker-compose.yml**
  `redis:`
    `image: "app-redis:cont"`
    `ports:`
      `- "6379:6379"`

**package.json**
`"deployRedis": "docker build . -f Dockerfile.redis -t app-redis:cont",`

**core.php**
`$engine = 'Redis';`
`Cache::config('default', [`
    `'engine' => $engine,`
    `'prefix' => $prefix . 'default_',`
    `'path' => CACHE . 'persistent' . DS,`
    `'serialize' => $serializingEngine,`
    `'duration' => $duration,`
`]);`

`Cache::config('_cake_core_', [`
    `'engine' => $engine,`
    `'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_core_',`
    `'path' => CACHE . 'persistent' . DS,`
    `'serialize' => $serializingEngine,`
    `'duration' => $duration,`
`]);`

When I debug **`extension_loaded('redis');`** I get a value of **true**

**Here is the error message dumped to the browser**
`Fatal error: Uncaught CacheException: Cache engine "default" is not properly configured. Ensure required extensions are installed, and credentials/permissions are correct in /var/www/html/public/app.name.local/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 190`

And finally, when I debug in the RedisEngine.php file in the connect method, from $e this is the error message:
`**"Connection refused"**`

If it is worth noting, I have checked to see what images are running within docker and I do see Redis:

`b38550ff4f38   app-redis:cont   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 seconds ago    Up 7 seconds    6379/tcp              app_redis.1.j0r12vgrsmv6hbtagcy3oj9vv`

Any advice is highly highly appreciated as I have been at this for almost 2 days.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in the php code?

https://api.cakephp.org/2.2/source-class-RedisEngine.html#63

```
array(
  'engine' => 'Redis',
  'prefix' => null,
  'server' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => 6379,
  'timeout' => 0,
  'persistent' => true
 )
```

Try:

```
Cache::config('default', [
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => $prefix . 'default_',
    'server' => 'redis', // docker || '127.0.0.1', <------------
    'port' => 6379, // <----------------
    'path' => CACHE . 'persistent' . DS,
    'serialize' => $serializingEngine,
    'duration' => $duration,
]);
```

Comment: You've made my week. Thank you SO very much. Changing the server to redis in RedisEngine.php solved the issue.

Comment: @Telah32 don't change in RedisEngine.php file, just add in your in `Cache::config('default', ... `and accept answer